# Using a node (express) web server to communicate with a python program

Tags: python, node.js, sockets, express, webserver

This is more of a best practices / design question.

Currently I have some application written in python that communicates with a simple node web server. I would like the web server to be able to communicate with this python process.

Now there seems to be many ways to do this:

1) design a socket that runs as a subprocess of the main process (using multiprocessing for instance) that listens on some port. Design a simple communication protocol on that socket.

2) have the web server write a file (such as json) that the python process periodically reads.

3) have the web server store an internal state corresponding to the desired message for the python process, which the python process periodically requests from the web server.

To me, each of these seem fine. However, modify my problem in that instead of having one python processes, you have hundreds, each of which have unique messages that need to be routed by the web server. 1) seems less attractive as you now need to manage ports you're using. 2) puts all the burden on file system choices. 3) may puts a heavier resource load on the server.

What is the better design choice out of those above, or are there better choices?

Comment: what manages/spawns the python threads ? Can't have that control the coms as well ?   use message queues on both sides via mutliple sockets ? Or use a message queuing library like MSMQ, ZeroMQ, RabbitMQ ? or even use redis or web workers ?

Comment: Ah, I should have mentioned: messages come to the web server from an external source (web page post requests). The server is meant to be a router for these messages. So unless each process has a unique listening socket, the best each process could do as far as communication would be to send requests to the server, no?

Comment: depends if you just have one or many servers (eg proxy the nodjs servers with nginx)

Comment: Thats one way. Do the python processes communicate with their parent or each other ?

Comment: At the moment, the number of servers is up for debate, but let's say that at the moment that there's a single server that needs to route the messages from the web interface to the python processes.

Comment: Each of the python processes do not communicate with each other.
Which parent? The main process is launched by `python`, but if there was a socket process, it would likely communicate with the main process with a pipe or shared variable of some sort.